# Print integers by using printf GAS

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

In the program below, I am trying to print out even numbers from 2 to n, with n passed in as an argument for function void even(int n). I have a different main.c file to call this function.

```
.extern printf
.section .data
format:
    .asciz "%d\n"

.section .text
.global even
even:
    cmpl $2, %edi #compare n to 2
    jl less_than_two #if n < 2 then jump to less_than_two
#if not, start from 2
    movl $2, %ebx           # start from 2

loop:
    # print the number
    movl $format, %esi # the string format of printf is in esi
    movl %ebx, %edi # the first argument of printf is in edi
    subq $8, %rsp # make room on the stack for the argument
    movl %edi, (%rsp) # push the argument onto the stack
    call printf
    addq $8, %rsp # clean up the stack

    addl $2, %ebx #add 2 to ebx
    cmpl %ebx, %edi # compare n with ebx
    jl end # if n < ebx then jump to end
    jmp loop #else continue to print

less_than_two:
    movl $format, %esi
    xorl %edi, %edi
    subq $8, %rsp # make room on the stack for the argument
    movl %edi, (%rsp) # push the argument onto the stack
    call printf
    addq $8, %rsp # clean up the stack
    ret

end:
    ret
```

When I try to compile and run it on Linux terminal, I get the result as: Segmentation fault (Core dumped).

Comment: Please, if you request is about assmbly language, don't tag it as `C`.  This is nonsense, and distracts people focused on C questions to check why you have tagged it in such a way.

Comment: How do you compile and link the code?  Please, edit your question and explain.

Answer (score 0):

In x86_64 Linux, arguments are passed in registers, not on the stack, so your printing code should be more like

```
    # print the number
    leaq format(%rip), %rdi   # the string format of printf is in rdi
    movl %ebx, %esi           # the first int argument of printf is in esi
    xor %eax, %eax            # set %al to 0 for no args in xmm regs
    call printf
```

See [the ABI spec](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/x86-64-ABI/abi.pdf?job=build) for all the gory details

Comment: RSP does have to be aligned by 16 before the call, so an odd number of push and 8-byte `sub` adjustments to RSP in the function prologue.  Modern builds of glibc printf do actually crash on misaligned RSP so this is important.  Also, the OP's code clobbers some of the caller's call-preserved registers like RBX, so later misbehaviour is also possible after returning.